# Showing table Shops data which is belongs_to table Countries, show in Country view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.8. I have this table Shops with the following data:

**Shops Database Table**

```
ID | country_id | notes
1  | 10         | test
2  | 10         | testing
3  | 12         | tested
```

In `shop.rb` I put `belongs_to :country`.

In my Country's `view.html.erb`, I want to be able to show the related `notes` from Shops table. Such in this case, in the page `http://localhost:3000/countries/10`, `notes` from ID1 and ID2 of Shops should appear in this page.

Can someone enlighten me how to achieve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add in country.rb `has_many :shops`. So now, from the html you can do

```
<% country.shops.each do |shop| %>
  <%= shop.notes %>
<% end %>
```

by adding the `has_many` you make the relationship bidirectional, and you can navigate to from shop -> country or from country -> shops.

Comment: Thanks Augusto. I am sorry that I can only accept one answer. So I am gonna accept Rafal's answer considering he made a reply first. I'm still thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `has_many :shops` in your Country model.

Than in your view you can loop over the shops

`<% @country.shops.each do |shop| %>`
`<%= shop.notes %>`
`<% end %>`

Hope this helps.